# Compile error in Erlang: "cannot parse file, giving up"

Tags: erlang

I'm just starting to look at Erlang and trying to compile my first program. Everything looks right compared to the tutorial but I can't seem to get away from this error.

Here is my code, saved under 'useless.erl':

```
-module(useless).
-export([add/2, hello/0, greet_and_add_two/1]).

add(A,B) ->
A + B. 

%% Shows greetings.
%% io:format/1 is the standard function used to output text.
hello() ->
io:format("Hello, world!~n").

greet_and_add_two(X) ->
hello(),
add(X,2).
```

I changed the directory to that of useless.erl:

```
cd("C:/Users/CP/Documents/Erlang").
```

However, when I run

```
c(useless).
```

I get

```
useless.erl:1: cannot parse file, giving up
useless.erl:1: no module definition
error
```

Comment: rename and recompile file. Code is good.

Comment: Save it with `ansi` or `utf-8` encoding.

Comment: Was saving without utf-8 encoding, thanks @Lol4t0!

Comment: @Lol4t0 you should add your comment as a real answer, so the OP can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your file looks OK, but Erlang compiler complaining that it can't parse the file, your code probably has invalid encoding.

According to the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/character_set.html) Erlang only accepts source code in `UTF-8` or `Latin-1` encodings.

> The valid encodings are Latin-1 and UTF-8, where the case of the characters can be chosen freely

Note that you still only able to use extended character set inside strings  and comments only:

> In Erlang/OTP R16B the syntax of Erlang tokens was extended to handle Unicode. The support is limited to string literals and comments.

In case of parse errors or illegal characters errors you should

1. Make sure your file is saved in `UTF-8` or `Latin-1` encoding
2. Make sure you do not use UTF literals outside of comments and strings
3. With older Erlang versions (before Erlang 17) you can try specify encoding explicitly in the file first two lines

   ```
   %% coding: utf-8
   %%% or
   %% For this file we have chosen encoding = Latin-1
   %%% or
   %% -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
   ```